# android navigating from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity

guys.

I'm trying to create a basic UI in Android, just for prototyping. 
I have an activity which basically offers a login screen with TextFiels for entering UserName and Password. Once these are verified, I want to show another activity that provides the authonticated user for doing some tasks. Can you give me a clue on how to this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This will start the other activity, and pass a variable Text

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), mynewActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("Text", txtString);
startActivityForResult(myIntent,101);
```

Answer (score 0):

add onClick to the button, and get username and password fields in onCreate

```
public void Login(View v)
{
    if(checkLogin(username, password))
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("USERNAME", username);
        i.putExtras(b);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Username or password incorrect", Toast.LENGH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```